# Symfony2, create querybuilder where clause, not empty or not null

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I've one type array field in Entity,

**MyEntity.php**

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="excepcionMenu", type="array", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $excepcion;
```

I would like to get a **QueryBuilder** to select **not empty** or **not null** in *$excepcion* field.

I'm trying
**MyEntityRepository.php**

```
public function findAllExcepcionesByItem($itemId) {

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->leftJoin('p.item', 'i')
            ->where('i.id = :actual')->setParameter('actual', $itemId)
            ->andWhere('p.excepcion IS NOT NULL')
            ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

But this returns all table records.

```php
public function findAllExcepcionesByItem($itemId) {

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->leftJoin('p.item', 'i')
            ->where('i.id = :actual')->setParameter('actual', $itemId)
            ->andWhere('p.excepcion IS NULL')
            ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

But this returns zero records.

this field in the database stores the values in this way:

```
a:0:{} // empty
N; // null
a:2:{i:0;i:2;i:1;i:4;} // not empty or not null
```

Is it possible to do this with QueryBuilder or should be done with DQL?

thanks a lot

---

**UPDATED solution** contributed by @Attila Szalay

```php
public function findAllExcepcionesByItem($itemId) {

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->leftJoin('p.item', 'i')
            ->where('i.id = :actual')->setParameter('actual', $itemId)
            ->andWhere('p.excepcion != :null')->setParameter('null', serialize(null)) //not null
            ->andWhere('p.excepcion != :empty')->setParameter('empty', serialize([])) //not empty
            ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Why $excepcion is string typing and column type is array?

Comment: because it has to save several possible options. Form on Twig renders several checkbox.

Comment: Do you know that an array cannot be null in PHP?

Comment: I know, but the array type in doctrine is not exactly an array in php. Removing `nullable=true` of the field definition in the entity, the result is the same, to create a new empty item, the value stored in the database is still `N;` and the query result too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data stored as [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) "string" in your database so NULL value will be a "N;" string and it is not a NULL value for db engines.

Try this:

```
 $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->leftJoin('p.item', 'i')
        ->where('i.id = :actual')->setParameter('actual', $itemId)
        ->andWhere('p.excepcion != :null')->setParameter('null', 'N;') //not null
        ->getQuery();
```

Comment: You're right, and had not fallen into this detail :) Now I only need check for `a:0:{}` thanks

Comment: You can use `serialize(null)` for NULL check instead of `'N;'` string and `serialize([])` for empty array.

Answer (score 15):

The other solution for the problem which worked for me is:

```
public function findAllExcepcionesByItem($itemId) {
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->leftJoin('p.item', 'i')
        ->where("i.id = :actual")->setParameter("actual", $itemId)
        ->andWhere("p.excepcion != ''") // NOT EMPTY
        ->andWhere("p.excepcion IS NOT NULL") // NOT NULL
        ->getQuery();
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Comment: `->andWhere("p.excepcion IN NOT NULL") // NOT NULL`
IN or IS ? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
$query = $qb->leftJoin('p.item', 'i')
        ->where('i.id = :actual')->setParameter('actual', $itemId)
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->isNotNull("p.excepcion"))
        ->getQuery();
```

In short you need to use the `Expr` class, [which is explained in further detail in the QueryBuilder chapter of Doctrine's documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html). I just showed you how to use it, however!

Comment: thank you very much, but the result is exactly the same as without using regular expressions. Like `->andWhere('p.excepcion IS NOT NULL')`. I think the problem is the type of field array.

Answer (score 0):

Your repository method is totally correct.

But, an array cannot be null. If it's null, then it's not an array: it's null.

The solution could be to change the type of the column `excepcionMenu`.

Comment: thank you @scoolnico, I have already answered this question in your comment on the main question.